# What are causes for Error 372 - Failed to Load Control Your version of <control.ocx> may be outdated

Tags: vb6

What are known causes for VB6 run-time Error 372 - Failed to Load Control Your version of  may be outdated.

I have a activceX control built from several standard windows controls and a Far Point.
The control is used in a VB6 desktop application.  The behavior I am seeing is that this active control fails occasionally on some workstations.  I have confirmed that the correct references are on the workstations.  The odd part is, the control will not fail right away.  It will work correctly on the Main form but fails when another form is opened.

It seems to be also tied with run-time 7 out of memory error.  When these errors typically occur no unusual CPU or memory usage is shown in Task Manager.

Seems the issue may related to MSCOMCT2.OCX.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First open up your form files (the file with the extension of FRM) in NOTEPAD makes sure the forms are truly referencing the same ActiveX Control. The references are near the top of the form. It is possible though uncommon that VB6 will mismatch the references between different forms.

Second look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942870) from Micrsoft. Make sure that the control is installed for All users and see if your problem goes way.

Problems like this are usually caused by a mismatch between the expected COM interface and the control that is loading.

Comment: I have eliminated the possibility that the user running the appis logged on under a different user account than the user account who installed the app.  I hadn't thought of references to the control on the form which may explain what I am seeing.  Cound the failure be sporadic with this case.

Comment: Yes I encountered instance where the reference in the frm didn't match the vbp file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that when I created my installation package (using InstallShield) that I needed to uncheck the "Filter Files" box in the dialog where INstallShield is setting up to scan the  Visual Basic project for dependencies. It was not packaging a MSDatgrd.ocx control of the VB Project into the setup, and that control was not in the Win 7 machine, so it threw this 372 message.

When I rebuilt my installation package for my software, and had it not filter files, it included that control and installed it on the target machine as part of the setup process and everything ran just fine.