# Random Vb6 error , usually for 'load control(array)' statement

Tags: vb6, ocx

> "Failed to load control 'A' from B.OCX.  Your version of B.OCX may be
>   outdated.  Make sure you are using the version of the control that was
>   provided with your application."

This error comes randomly in vb6 application exe, will not repeat when application is closed and opened (i.e can't recreate error)
usually comes for 'load control(array)' statement

What is the cause for this error? (registration of ocx file is done properly, also it works most of the time)

tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/619144/1997066) , but same error repeats.

Comment: You are probably leaking GDI handles. Effectively this is an OOM error message, disguised with mystic numbers. . .

Comment: @wqw GDI handles are less than 2000

Comment: @wqw GDI handles are between 2k to 3k when the program is running.