# msdbrptr.dll get error 372 windows 7 64 bit

Tags: vb6

Run-time error '372':
Failed to load control 'DataReport' from C: \ WINDOWS \ SysWOW64 \ Msdbrptr.dll. Your version of the C: \ WINDOWS \ SysWOW64 \ Msdbrptr.dll may be outdated. Make sure you are using the version of the control That was provided with your application.

https://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=167589&d=1555473527

my application work by vb6.

Msdbrptr.dll version 6.0.81.69 year 2018.

can anyone help me ?

Comment: Take a look at [What are causes for Error 372 - Failed to Load Control Your version of <control.ocx> may be outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619144/what-are-causes-for-error-372-failed-to-load-control-your-version-of-control?rq=1)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.