# How can I solve or fix Run Time Error "372" Msdbrptr.dll?

Tags: vb6, ms-office

my application work by vb6.

The Error occur after install Office 2015. Before installing Office 2015 will by my program worked.

Msdbrptr.dll version 6.0.81.69 year 2018.

[image]

> Run-time error '372': Failed to load control 'DataReport' from C: 
> WINDOWS \ SysWOW64 \ Msdbrptr.dll. Your version of the C: \ WINDOWS 
> SysWOW64 \ Msdbrptr.dll may be outdated. Make sure you are using the
> version of the control That was provided with your application.

I delete Msdbrptr.dll then add it but same error exist.

can anyone help me ?

Comment: What does "Microsoft 2015" mean?

Comment: install Microsoft 2015 to my computer after it error pop up

Comment: There is nothing called "Microsoft 2015". Do you mean OFFICE 2015 maybe?

Comment: correct it is mean

Comment: Have you tried using regsvr32 on the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft KB 942870:

> **Action**
>
> You attempt to run a Visual Basic 6.0 application that contains an
> ActiveX control.
>
> **Result**
>
> You receive the following error message:
>
> Runtime Error: 372 - Failed to load control  from
> <control.ocx>.Your version of <control.ocx> may be outdated. Make sure
> you are using the version of the control that was provided with your
> application
>
> **Cause**
>
> This can occur when the user running the application is logged on
> under a different user account than the user account who installed the
> application, and the installation package installed the application on
> a per user basis.
>
> When an application is installed for a specific user, the COM
> components referenced in the application are registered in the
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive in the Windows registry. When an application is
> installed for All Users, the registry entries are made to the
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive in the Windows registry, and all users should
> be able to read these entries by default.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Modify the installation program to install the application for All
> Users.

Comment: Thanks. but my program not use installation. It work directly. The Error occur after install Microsoft 2015 before install MS 2015 will by my program worked.

Comment: Search your registry for Msdbrptr.dll. Usually it's in
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{642AC760-AAB4-11D0-8494-00A0C90DC8A9}

If there is no such registry entry, register your Msdbrptr.dll with regsvr32 utility (as admin).

Comment: Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619144/what-are-causes-for-error-372-failed-to-load-control-your-version-of-control?rq=1