# Run-time error ‘372’ – failed to load control ‘AdvGrid’ from AdvGridProj.ocx

Tags: vb6

> Run-time error ‘372’ – failed to load control ‘AdvGrid’ from
> AdvGridProj.ocx. Your version dkztexbox.ocx may be outdated. Make sure
> you are using the version of the control that was provided with your
> application.

on widows 7 and 10

how can solve it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are causes for Error 372 - Failed to Load Control Your version of <control.ocx> may be outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619144/what-are-causes-for-error-372-failed-to-load-control-your-version-of-control)

Comment: This does sound like a dupe except that it refers to two different OCX libraries in the cited error. Is one a dependency of the other?

Comment: AdvGridProj.ocx is main and AdvGrid.ocx is sub

Comment: Did you make sure dkztexbox was successfully registered?